# Examine the uniform continuity $f(x)=(e^{x}-1)\sin\frac{1}{3^x-1}$ for $x \in (0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

**My try:**
I know that if for all $x_{n},y_{n}$ condidion $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(x_{n}-y_{n})=0$ implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})=0$ then $f$ is uniform continuity.
Let: $$x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$ $$y_{n}=\frac{1}{2n}$$Then:$$x_{n}-y_{n}=\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow 0$$
$$f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})=(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\sin\frac{1}{3^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}-(e^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1)\sin\frac{1}{3^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1}$$
I know that $f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})$ is periodic so $\lim \neq 0$ so I find counterexample that $f$ is uniform continuity.
However I don't know how I can show it in a professional way.
Have you some idea?

Comment: You are just showing for one particular sequence, that is not a proof.

Comment: @copper.hat But the OP is trying to show UC fails.

Comment: @zhw.: It is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes I know, but the OP believes otherwise. So looking for one sequence is decent strategy in attempting to show it's not UC,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and combine
this with uniform continuity of continuous functions on compact intervals to show that
$f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

This limit is equal to zero because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (e^{\frac1{kn}}-1)=0$$
given that $k\in\mathbb{R}$, $k\ne0$. As $\sin{(x)}$ is bounded for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the value of the two multiplied together is still zero. Also $f(x_n)-f(y_n)$ is not periodic.